# Need Excel Formula help Needed

Tags: excel-formula

I've got a weekly aging report for some projects. It's created in Excel-sheet

In my data A columns have more values in different sign positive & negatives

In my data B columns have DR\CR

Output I need - In C columns, if DR in columns all numbers converted to positive in columns and CR means all number converted to negative in C columns.

```
A column B Column C Column
-100       D         100
-200       D         200
 300       C        -300
-400       C        -400
 500       D         500
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (and I'm not really sure at this point, please be more coherent next time with your question) you just need basic if condition

```
=IF(B1="D",ABS(A1),ABS(A1)*(-1))
```

or if you have more letters in your B column:

```
=IF(B1="d",ABS(A1),IF(B1="C",ABS(A1)*(-1),0))
```